# How to solved small validation problem (It is practically finished, except for a small detail ..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Question originally [posted in Spanish, on es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/297642/peque%c3%b1o-problema-de-validaci%c3%b3n-est%c3%a1-pr%c3%a1cticamente-acabada-salvo-por-un-peque%c3%b1o), by [Julian Dumitrel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/138337/julian-dumitrel):

> I had planned to make a record, by steps, that I had 3, **all these
> steps are in one** `<form>`.
>
> I have finally finished my form validator, which is functional as I
> wanted , now I have another problem, and that is that when I click on
> the submit button, still leaving the fields empty, the registration
> makes fadeOut (something that does not should do, unless all fields
> have value, and are validated using the functions I created)
>
> ```js
> $(function() {
>
>   var error_username = false;
>   var error_password = false;
>   var error_password_confirm = false;
>   var error_email = false;
>
>   $("#username").focusout(function() {
>
>     check_username();
>
>   });
>   $("#password").focusout(function() {
>
>     check_password();
>
>   });
>   $("#password-confirm").focusout(function() {
>
>     check_password_confirm();
>
>   });
>   $("#email").focusout(function() {
>
>     check_email();
>
>   });
>
>   function check_username() {
>     var username_length = $("#username").val().length;
>
>     if (username_length < 3 || username_length > 20) {
>       $("input#username").addClass("invalid");
>       error_username = true;
>     } else {
>       $("input#username").removeClass("invalid");
>     }
>   }
>
>   function check_password() {
>     var password_length = $("#password").val().length;
>
>     if (password_length < 6) {
>       $("input#password").addClass("invalid");
>       error_password = true;
>     } else {
>       $("input#password").removeClass("invalid");
>     }
>   }
>
>   function check_password_confirm() {
>     var password_confirm_length = $("#password-confirm").val().length;
>     var password = $("#password").val();
>     var password_confirm = $("#password-confirm").val();
>
>     //if (password_confirm_length < 6)
>     //{
>     //  $("input#password-confirm").addClass("invalid");
>     // error_password_confirm = true;
>     //}
>     if (password != password_confirm) {
>       $("input#password-confirm").addClass("invalid");
>       $("input#password").addClass("invalid");
>       // msg.... (password doesn't match)
>       error_password_confirm = true;
>     } else {
>       $("input#password-confirm").removeClass("invalid");
>       $("input#password").removeClass("invalid");
>     }
>   }
>
>   function check_email() {
>     var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);
>
>     if (pattern.test($("#email").val())) {
>       $("input#email").removeClass("invalid");
>     } else {
>       $("input#email").addClass("invalid");
>       error_email = true;
>     }
>   }
>
>
>
>   // Aquí deriva el problema que no hace submit correctamente
>   $("#submitir").click(function() {
>
>     event.preventDefault();
>     var error_username = false;
>     var error_password = false;
>     var error_password_confirm = false;
>     var error_email = false;
>
>     check_username();
>     check_password();
>     check_password_confirm();
>     check_email();
>
>     if (error_username == false && error_password == false && error_password_confirm == false && error_email == false) {
>       $("div.primer-step").fadeOut(550, function() {
>         $("div.segundo-step").fadeIn(550);
>       });
>     } else {
>       return false;
>     }
>   });
>
>
> });
>
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
> <html>
> <div class="primer-step">
>   <center>
>     <h1>Crear Cuenta</h1>
>   </center>
>
>   <form id="register-form" action="" method="post">
>     <label for="username">Nombre de usuario:</label>
>     <input type="text" id="username"><span class="error-form" id="username-error-message"></span>
>     <label for="username">Contraseña:</label>
>     <input type="password" id="password">
>     <br><br>
>     <label for="username">Confirma contraseña :</label>
>     <input type="password" id="password-confirm">
>     <label for="email">Email:</label>
>     <input type="email" id="email">
>     <br><br><br>
>     <center><input type="submit" value="avanzar a paso 2" id="submitir"></center>
>   </form>
>
> </div>
> <div class="segundo-step" style="display:none;">
>   <h1>Validator completado! :D</h1>
> </div>
>
>
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
>
> </html>
>
> >
> ```
>
> The truth is that I don't know why it should be peeling, since at first sight everything is fine, besides everything is tested, I should not let pass, if the fields are not validated, **in the submit function, if it does not validate correctly, it makes a "return false", perhaps it is that which is failing, what I intend with that is that it does not simply pass.**
>
> My form, the original has many more lines, and the controller more of the same, with which everything is already programmed by the back-end part with its models, which making more forms would not be feasible for me at all, the only What fails me is this.

Comment: FYI: The `<center>` element has been deprecated since HTML 4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the error-variables in the click-handler on your submit-button are independent from the ones you set in the validation functions and thus the condition for the if-block is met.

The solution: remove the `var`s in front of the error-variables in you click-handler.